# fetching uuid from remote device using xamarin android

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin

I want to read out a bluetooth device and must specify the right uuid for it. I know there is a java function something like fetchuuid but that function is not available in the android.mono API. How can I call this function using c#?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The `BluetoothDevice.getUuid()` is available from Android 4.0.3 so upgrade your build configurations to match this. That is set minimum to Android 4.0.3 (API 15)

Answer (score 0):

The `BluetoothDevice.getUuid()` is available from Android 4.0.3 so upgrade your build configurations to match this.